# Preload stuff automatically?

Tags: lubuntu, preload

Is there a way to configure preload or another thing that does the same thing to pre-load Chrome or other specific applications by default ?

I rarely run out of ram and use this machine for browsing and video only pretty much.
Start-up time for chrome without preload is pretty slow, so I'm looking into getting it auto 'pre-loaded' at boot.

I use Lubuntu 14.04 if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a program that was developed that does just this, titled `GOPreload`, but it is not available in the official repos or any Ubuntu PPA. If you are interested, you can find the source code for it [here](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-622085-highlight-preload.html).